# Installation of OpenCV 2.4.10 on Microsoft Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2008

I followed the guide in this link to configure the OpenCV in Microsoft Visual studio 2008

> [Installation of OpenCV 2.4.5 on Visual Studio 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574959/installation-of-opencv-2-4-5-on-visual-studio-2008)

and i use the sample codes from openCV

> http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html

[image]

and I got this error whenever I run it.

[image]

Can some one please tell me how do I fix this?

======
EDIT ***

After several research I had discovered that I have to use VC9 instead of VC11 for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008

> [MSVCP120d.dll missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21707992/msvcp120d-dll-missing)

But the latest version of the OpenCV which is OpenCV 2.4.10.exe do not have the VC9. and It only have VC11, VC10 and also VC12.

Is the latest version of OpenCV is not campatible with Microsoft Visual studio 2008? Which version of OpenCV that is compatible with Microsoft Visual Studio 2008?

Thank you.

Comment: there are probably no more prebuild libs for vs 2008, and you **can't** use the vs2010 ones. if you have to use vs2008, get cmake, and build opencv from src.

Comment: Shouldn't ^^ this just be the answer not a comment? It's right.

Comment: @berak thank you for the information but may I know how do I "cmake, and build opencv from src"? I had already downloaded cmake

Comment: @GPPK , ^^ i'm not sure, if i want to write a complete, n00b safe tutorial on how to build for vs2008 with cmake right now. you, maybe ?

Comment: @berak uhh sorry, I am really a noob in C++, image processing and microsoft visual studio, and I am currently doing research and learning =D. I will appreciate it very much if you can give me some guides. Thanking you in anticipation. =D

Comment: @AuroraBlaze , don't feel sorry,  none of us was *born* with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But the latest version of the OpenCV which is OpenCV 2.4.10.exe do not
>   have the VC9. and It only have VC11, VC10 and also VC12.

Correct, there are no longer prebuilt libs for VS2008.

> Is the latest version of OpenCV is not campatible with Microsoft
>   Visual studio 2008? Which version of OpenCV that is compatible with
>   Microsoft Visual Studio 2008?

Well, they all are, but you have to compile the libraries from the source code provided by OpenCV using CMAKE.

> may I know how do I "cmake, and build opencv from src"? I had already downloaded cmake

[This Guide](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html) on the OpenCV Wedsite talks through how to compile from CMAKE, there are also other guides that are available through Google. I would suggest attempting to follow the linked tutorial and if you get stuck asking another question that is more relevant to that specific problem.

Comment: okay, and thank you for the explanations and also for the link. I appreciate it =D.