# opencv split hsv images

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to split an image into h,s and v channels. But an error occured every time and the reason seems to be that **opencv `split` function does not work properly**.

My code:

```
Mat src, srcHSV;
Mat srcH;
vector<Mat> channels;
VideoCapture cap(0);
for(int frame = 0; ; frame++)
{
    cap >> src;

    imshow("camera image", src)；
    cvWaitKey(1);

    cvtColor(src, srcHSV, CV_BGR2HSV);
    imshow("hsv image", srcHSV);
    cvWaitKey(1);

    split(srcHSV, channels);
    srcH =  channels[0];
    ...  //do something with srcH
}
```

Camera image and hsv image are OK. But when it executes `srcH = channels[0]`, an error message says:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x012d1602 in xxx.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000014.
```

I set a breakpoint here and checked the value of `channels`. It comprises of many elements, but each element is an unknown object.
[image: channels]
I saw a post talking about the similar problem but there was no answer. [split image to 3 channels opencv error](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/96112/).

**[solved]**
According to @nowaqq 's comments and @Andrey Smorodov 's answer, my code now looks like this:

```
for(int frame =0 ; ; frame ++)
  {
    vector<Mat> channels; //put the channels declaration inside the for-loop

    cap >> src;

    imshow("camera image", src);
    cvWaitKey(1);
    srcHSV = Mat::zeros(Size(src.rows, src.cols), CV_8UC3);
    cvtColor(src, srcHSV, CV_BGR2HSV);
    imshow("hsv image", srcHSV);
    cvWaitKey(1);

    channels.clear();
    channels.resize(srcHSV.channels());  //resize channels
    cv::split(srcHSV, &channels[0]);  //&channels[0] instead of channels as the second parameter to split function
    srcH = channels[0];
    ...//do something with srcH
 }
```

**[updated]**
I struggled to solve another problem, this problem was also solved as a side-effect. See my answer below.

Comment: opencv doc says: "in the first variant of the function the number of arrays must match src.channels(); the arrays themselves are reallocated, if needed." Have you tried doing `channels.resize(srcHSV.channels())` before calling split?

Comment: @nowaqq Thank you for pointing that. I tried  `channels.resized(srcHSV.channels()) before calling split` just now, `channels` now contains only three elements, but each element is still a very strange object with `dims`, 'rows' and `cols` all equaling to zero, and `data` a bad pointer. That means I cannot use `channels` or any channel.

Comment: Also, since split expects a pointer, I think you should pass &channels[0] instead of vector.

Comment: if srcHSV isn't empty, your code should work imho. Can you check your openCV installation?? Can you try a different openCV version? Can you try cv::split? Maybe there are multiple functions with name split in your environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution seems unrelated to this question but indeed it solves the problem!
Since I'm debugging my image processing code, my solution configuration is `debug` and platform `win32`, but when I was configuring my project, to make it "more compatible", I add release and debug libs path, and add two versions of libs as dependency, for example, opencv_calib3d2412.lib(release version library) and opencv_calib3d2412**d**.lib(debug version library). In brief, I set up the opencv+vs2008+(C++ project) following [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574959/installation-of-opencv-2-4-5-on-visual-studio-2008). By the way, Step 7 in that question description is really misleading. Or maybe I misunderstand it. After I remove the release lib path and release version libs from dependency, it works well.
The wrong configuration leads to another problem except the one I described above. The title of the window shows some strange charactors. To solve that problem, [solution here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/46777/capture-window-has-strange-ascii-characters/) saved me from all the weird things.

Answer (score 1):

Put channels declaration into loop, split seems pushes more and more Mat into vector, and these Mats are become broken next iteration. Or clean it each time, before use split.